# Multiple button OnClickListener not doing anything. (Using a switch)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make an app homepage that will lead on to some other of my app ideas.
The homepage consists of 6 Buttons, and I want them to lead to their own individual pages when clicked on. To check if the buttons work, I have used toasts (Once the toasts work i'll change them into intents).

Here is my code, to simplify and shorten the code I've only shown the code following one button, but the same code applies for 5 others in my android studio.

First of all, XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/spotify_button"
    android:text="Spotify Streamer"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button spotify = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spotify_button);


        spotify.setOnClickListener(buttonz);



    }

    private View.OnClickListener buttonz = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {

                case R.id.spotify_button:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;
```

As someone very new to Java and Android, this is how I understand the code works:

In the onCreate section, I create a button called "spotify" which is cast to the XML button.
I then set an onClickListener called "buttonz" on this button. Once the "computer" sees this it looks for the section I made (View.OnClickListener), which sees that it works on click, so it thinks "do something when the button is clicked we will handle click here but which button clicked??? It doesn't know, and that's when the switch comes into place.
Everything seems to link up so I don't know why when i open the app on my phone and click the button nothing happens?

Anyways, if someone could help me make this work I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the main problem but try adding .show() after your Toast call, like: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Worked. Can't believe it was something that simple, thanks a lot! :)